# Black Screen after Huawei login, caused by InputRealNameActivitys

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-account

### Environment

- OS: Android10
- Model: Huawei Honor 10
- SDK: hwid 5.0.4

### Problem describe

Test brid report there are **black screen** found in our app with few specific devices.

As we reproduced, the black screen happen after we called **Huawei login method**. And black screen is disappear after we click Android back button.

### useful info

As we dig into, the top activity that make screen black is `com.huawei.hwid20.inputrealname.InputRealNameActivity`, and more, as we search in the logcat, we found following lines that you may interesting:

```
06-18 10:13:55.326   700  3444 E BufferQueueProducer: [com.huawei.hwid/com.huawei.hwid20.inputrealname.InputRealNameActivity#0]:1338: disconnect: not connected (req=1)
06-18 10:13:55.326 12947 15847 W libEGL  : EGLNativeWindowType 0x7ae5fab910 disconnect failed
06-18 10:13:55.319 14683 14683 W GameMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:65405): avc: granted { read } for pid=14683 name="a0" dev="sdcardfs" ino=55427 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=dir
06-18 10:13:55.319 14683 14683 W GameMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:65406): avc: granted { read } for pid=14683 name="a0" dev="sdcardfs" ino=55427 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=dir
06-18 10:13:55.319 14683 14683 W GameMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:65407): avc: granted { read open } for pid=14683 path="/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.syzh.jsxw.huawei/files/patch/a0" dev="sdcardfs" ino=55427 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=dir
06-18 10:13:55.319 14683 14683 W GameMain: type=1400 audit(0.0:65408): avc: granted { write } for pid=14683 name="a0" dev="sdcardfs" ino=55427 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=dir
06-18 10:13:55.303  1474  1842 D HwGameAssistantController: Keycontrol mode is 2 for user 0
06-18 10:13:55.328  1474  3047 V WindowManager: removeIfPossible: Window{bfd80e1 u0 com.huawei.hwid/com.huawei.hwid20.inputrealname.InputRealNameActivity} callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:5504348 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:5502984 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:7520340 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:6765932 android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal:8316500 
06-18 10:13:55.328  1474  3047 D HwAppTransitionImpl: windowAnimations = 2060168 dose not come from system, not to override it.
06-18 10:13:55.330 16001 16001 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-18 10:13:55.331  1474  3047 V WindowManager: Not removing Window{bfd80e1 u0 com.huawei.hwid/com.huawei.hwid20.inputrealname.InputRealNameActivity EXITING} due to exit animation
06-18 10:13:55.332  1474  1501 I StatusBarDisable: setFlags what=0 which=1 pkg=Window{bfd8171 u0 com.huawei.hwid/com.huawei.hwid20.inputrealname.InputRealNameActivity}
06-18 10:13:55.332  1474  3047 D ZrHung.AppEyeTransparentWindow: TransparentWindow mHungConfigStatus = 0,mHungConfigEnable = 1
06-18 10:13:55.346 12947 12947 W InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
06-18 10:13:55.346   700   700 D SurfaceFlinger: Found SecureRecScreen Layer
06-18 10:13:55.346  1474  4353 E InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{bfd80e1 u0 com.huawei.hwid/com.huawei.hwid20.inputrealname.InputRealNameActivity} has no registered input channel
```

So we think the SDK was trying to remove `InputRealNameActivity` but failed due to `exit animation`.

In our brain storm opinion, we are thinking some animation play failed due to device issue, and this failed animation prevent the destroy of `InputRealNameActivity`, so it leaves in the screen.

Anyway what we can confirm is, an Activity `InputRealNameActivity` from huawei SDK do make the screen black, and users may have no idea how to cancel it, it hurts our user experience and I believe it hurts Huawei's user as well.

### Reproduce

As what we know, it is not a common case, so you can not produce it easily, luckily we found a device in test brid could reproduce it.

enter here, https://www.testbird.com/ , login, and search for Huawei Honor, you'll find there is only one Huawei Honor 10 device, that device could reproduce it easily. Just run the app, and tigger Huawei account login.

Thank you in advance, if the team could take a look about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the team, this issue is caused by security considerations.

The screen recording prevention and screen capture prevention functions are provided on the account login page. Then the device in test brid may have triggered this security mechanism, so it goes black screen.

Comment: Thanks shirley for the quick reply. The answer make scene to me. 
Yeah, we are not able to reproduce it in any real device. We'll do more test to make sure this is the cause and probably get back here.

Comment: You're welcome.You can test it on the Huawei real device.After the screen recording function is enabled, when you open the login page, a black screen will displayed in all recorded videos that involve passwords.